# progress bar when file download in electron application using node.js

Tags: ios, node.js, windows, progress-bar, electron

I want to show a progress bar when my video file download in the electron desktop application using node.js

I had alredy tried progressbar.js library but it only show when the downloading is completed.

The bellow is the part of my code where I am using the progressbar.js library.

```
componentDidMount(){

    this.bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(this.refs.downloadLoader, {
        strokeWidth: 3,
        easing: 'easeOut',
        duration: 1000,
        color: '#0c9928',
        trailColor: 'red',
        trailWidth: 0.3,
        svgStyle: 'block',
        trailWidth: 100% 
    })
```

Please suggest me any alternative library or the way how to use the gif in electron application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently implemented progress bar for my electron app.
Progress bar code taken from here : https://scriptscodes.com/simeydotme/battle-net-style-progress-bar-IrGqz

Please check if this can help you

progressbar.css

```
.progress {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 146px;
    background: rgb(129, 171, 144);
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.progress--active .progress__bar {
    opacity: 1;
}
.progress__text {
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0 0.9em;
    position: absolute;
}
.progress__text em {
    font-style: normal;
}
.progress__bar {
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    line-height: 19px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    background-size: 100px 30px, 130px 30px, 130px 30px;
    background-position: -20% center, right center, left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, width 0.8s ease-out, background-color 1s ease, border-color 0.3s ease, box-shadow 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease, width 0.8s ease-out, background-color 1s ease, border-color 0.3s ease, box-shadow 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-out infinite;
    animation: pulse 2s ease-out infinite;
    background-color: rgba(201, 4, 20, 0.95);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(226, 4, 22, 0) 10%, rgba(250, 6, 26, 0.8) 30%, #fb1f31 70%, rgba(250, 6, 26, 0.8) 80%, rgba(226, 4, 22, 0) 90%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(251, 31, 49, 0) 0%, #fb1f31 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(251, 31, 49, 0) 0%, #fb1f31 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(226, 4, 22, 0) 10%, rgba(250, 6, 26, 0.8) 30%, #fb1f31 70%, rgba(250, 6, 26, 0.8) 80%, rgba(226, 4, 22, 0) 90%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(251, 31, 49, 0) 0%, #fb1f31 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(251, 31, 49, 0) 0%, #fb1f31 100%);
    border-color: #fb3848;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #fa061a inset, 0 0 0.4em #e20416 inset, 0 0 0.5em rgba(201, 4, 20, 0.5), 0 0 0.1em rgba(254, 206, 210, 0.5);
}
.progress__bar--orange {
    background-color: rgba(201, 47, 0, 0.95);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(227, 53, 0, 0) 10%, rgba(252, 59, 0, 0.8) 30%, #ff4d17 70%, rgba(252, 59, 0, 0.8) 80%, rgba(227, 53, 0, 0) 90%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 77, 23, 0) 0%, #ff4d17 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 77, 23, 0) 0%, #ff4d17 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(227, 53, 0, 0) 10%, rgba(252, 59, 0, 0.8) 30%, #ff4d17 70%, rgba(252, 59, 0, 0.8) 80%, rgba(227, 53, 0, 0) 90%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 77, 23, 0) 0%, #ff4d17 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 77, 23, 0) 0%, #ff4d17 100%);
    border-color: #ff6030;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #fc3b00 inset, 0 0 0.4em #e33500 inset, 0 0 0.5em rgba(201, 47, 0, 0.5), 0 0 0.1em rgba(255, 214, 201, 0.5);
}
.progress__bar--yellow {
    background-color: rgba(232, 158, 0, 0.95);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 174, 3, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 183, 28, 0.8) 30%, #ffbf36 70%, rgba(255, 183, 28, 0.8) 80%, rgba(255, 174, 3, 0) 90%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 191, 54, 0) 0%, #ffbf36 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 191, 54, 0) 0%, #ffbf36 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 174, 3, 0) 10%, rgba(255, 183, 28, 0.8) 30%, #ffbf36 70%, rgba(255, 183, 28, 0.8) 80%, rgba(255, 174, 3, 0) 90%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 191, 54, 0) 0%, #ffbf36 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 191, 54, 0) 0%, #ffbf36 100%);
    border-color: #ffc74f;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #ffb71c inset, 0 0 0.4em #ffae03 inset, 0 0 0.5em rgba(232, 158, 0, 0.5), 0 0 0.1em rgba(255, 248, 232, 0.5);
}
.progress__bar--green {
    background-color: rgba(0, 178, 23, 0.95);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 204, 26, 0) 10%, rgba(0, 229, 30, 0.8) 30%, #00ff21 70%, rgba(0, 229, 30, 0.8) 80%, rgba(0, 204, 26, 0) 90%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 255, 33, 0) 0%, #00ff21 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 255, 33, 0) 0%, #00ff21 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 204, 26, 0) 10%, rgba(0, 229, 30, 0.8) 30%, #00ff21 70%, rgba(0, 229, 30, 0.8) 80%, rgba(0, 204, 26, 0) 90%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 255, 33, 0) 0%, #00ff21 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 255, 33, 0) 0%, #00ff21 100%);
    border-color: #19ff37;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #00e51e inset, 0 0 0.4em #00cc1a inset, 0 0 0.5em rgba(0, 178, 23, 0.5), 0 0 0.1em rgba(178, 255, 188, 0.5);
}
.progress__bar--blue {
    background-color: rgba(18, 135, 204, 0.95);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(20, 151, 227, 0) 10%, rgba(37, 162, 236, 0.8) 30%, #3dacee 70%, rgba(37, 162, 236, 0.8) 80%, rgba(20, 151, 227, 0) 90%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(61, 172, 238, 0) 0%, #3dacee 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(61, 172, 238, 0) 0%, #3dacee 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(20, 151, 227, 0) 10%, rgba(37, 162, 236, 0.8) 30%, #3dacee 70%, rgba(37, 162, 236, 0.8) 80%, rgba(20, 151, 227, 0) 90%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(61, 172, 238, 0) 0%, #3dacee 100%), linear-gradient(to left, rgba(61, 172, 238, 0) 0%, #3dacee 100%);
    border-color: #54b6f0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #25a2ec inset, 0 0 0.4em #1497e3 inset, 0 0 0.5em rgba(18, 135, 204, 0.5), 0 0 0.1em rgba(225, 242, 252, 0.5);
}
.progress__bar:before, .progress__bar:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    top: -10px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 40px;
}
.progress__bar:before {
    width: 7px;
    right: -4px;
    //background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center ellipse, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%);
}
.progress__bar:after {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
.progress--complete .progress__bar {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.progress--complete .progress__bar:after, .progress--complete .progress__bar:before {
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        background-position: -50% center, right center, left center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 150% center, right center, left center;
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        background-position: -50% center, right center, left center;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 150% center, right center, left center;
    }
}
```

Electron render process : downloader.js

```
const {session} = require('electron').remote;

session.defaultSession.on('will-download', function(event, downloadItem, webContents){

    "use strict";
    console.log("dowloader is called with event "+ event + " webContents "+ webContents);

    if(downloadItem.getTotalBytes() === 0){
        swal({
            position: 'center',
            type: 'error',
            title: 'File is empty !!',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            timer: 3000
        });
    }

    downloadItem.on('updated', function (event, state) {

        console.log("download item event triggred " + event + state);

        if (state === 'interrupted') {
            console.log('Download is interrupted but can be resumed');
        }else if (state === 'progressing') {

            console.log("download is processing");

            let jQueryprogress = jQuery(".progress");
            let jQuerybar = jQuery(".progress__bar");
            let jQuerytext = jQuery(".progress__text");
            let percent = 0;
            let update;
            let resetColors;
            let speed = 200;
            let orange = 30;
            let yellow = 55;
            let green = 85;
            let timer;

            resetColors = function() {
                jQuerybar
                    .removeClass("progress__bar--green")
                    .removeClass("progress__bar--yellow")
                    .removeClass("progress__bar--orange")
                    .removeClass("progress__bar--blue");

                jQueryprogress
                    .removeClass("progress--complete");

            };

            update = function() {
                timer = setTimeout( function() {
                    console.log("running");

                    try{
                        let percentage = downloadItem.getReceivedBytes()/downloadItem.getTotalBytes();
                        percent =  percentage * 100;
                        percent = parseFloat( percent.toFixed(2) );
                        update();

                    }catch (error){

                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        console.log("Error while try to calculate received bytes inside downloader "+ error);
                        percent = 100;
                        resetColors();
                        jQueryprogress.addClass("progress--complete");
                        jQuerybar.addClass("progress__bar--blue");
                        jQuerytext.find("em").text( "Complete" );
                        percent = 0;

                    }

                    jQuerytext.find("em").text( percent + "%" );
                    if( percent >= green ) {
                        jQuerybar.addClass("progress__bar--green");
                    }

                    else if( percent >= yellow ) {
                        jQuerybar.addClass("progress__bar--yellow");
                    }

                    else if( percent >= orange ) {
                        jQuerybar.addClass("progress__bar--orange");
                    }

                    speed = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );

                    jQuerybar.css({ width: percent + "%" });

                }, speed);

            };

            jQuery(".progress").show();
            jQueryprogress.addClass("progress--active");
            update();
            resetColors();
        }

    });



    downloadItem.once('done', function(event, state) {

        console.log("Inside download done function "+ event + state);

        if (state === 'completed') {
            setTimeout(function(){

                jQuery(".progress").hide();
                swal({
                    position: 'center',
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'File downloded successfully !',
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    timer: 3000
                });

            }, 50);

        } else if (state === 'cancelled'||state === "interrupted"){

            jQuery(".progress").hide();
            console.log("downloas cancelled");

            swal({
                position: 'center',
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Download cancelled or interrupted !!',
                showConfirmButton: true,
                timer: 2000
            });


        } else {
            jQuery(".progress").hide();
            swal({
                position: 'center',
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Download failed !!',
                showConfirmButton: true,
                timer: 2000
            });

        }
    });


    session.defaultSession.clearStorageData([], function () {console.log(' cleared all storages after download ');});
    session.defaultSession.clearCache(function(){console.log('cleared all caches after download');});

});
```

Html code :

```
    <div class="progress" style="display: none">
        <b class="progress__bar">
    <span class="progress__text">
      Progress: <em>0%</em>
    </span>
        </b>
    </div>

<a href="yoururl" download  id="downloadreport" style="display: none">Download Report</a>
```

Comment: I need to render the percentage to another page but it doesn't show there until i reload the page. Also i want to show the multiple value in downloading.

Comment: In addition to this $text.find("em").text( percent + "%" ); add  $text.find("your-newpage-idorclass").text( percent + "%" );  I never tried multiple values you can experiment with the above code